# Unrecognized escape character in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, configurationmanager

I have the following piece of code in my .cs file :

```
string connectionString= "SUMAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=northwind;Integrated Security=True";
```

It produce error as unrecognized escape character for the "\" character.How to solve this?

***Note***:Its in the .cs file not in the web.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't escapte the backslashes. this can be done like

```
string connectionString= @"SUMAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=northwind;Integrated Security=True";
```

-> string prefixed by @

OR

```
string connectionString= "SUMAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=northwind;Integrated Security=True";
```

-> prefix backslash with another one

Comment: It worked..thanks. Do you mind telling me what does @ do

Comment: it is called verbatim string escaping. what it does is treating backslashes as normal characters.